# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch with a google app using the Big Query API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Hi so I have been trying to make an app that uses a Biq Query API.

All the authentication and client secrets for OAuth2 work fine when I load the app locally, however after deploying the code I get the following error:

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
Request Details

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
response_type=code
redirect_uri=https://terradata-test.appspot.com/oauth2callback
access_type=offline
state=https://terradata-test.appspot.com/
display=page
client_id=660103924069.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

But looking at my API Console, I find that the redirect uri https://terradata-test.appspot.com/oauth2callback is in my list or redirect uri's:

> Redirect URIs:
>
> 1.https://terradata-test.appspot.com/oauth2callback
>
> 2.http://terradata-test.appspot.com/oauth2callback
>
> 3.http://1.terradata-test.appspot.com/oauth2callback
>
> 4.https://code.google.com/oauthplayground

I'm not sure what I'm missing to fix this problem? Why is there a redirect error with a uri that is listed in the API console?

The app builds the OAuth2 decorator to pass through to the Biq Query API like this:

```
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
   'client_secrets.json')

decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

http = httplib2.Http(memcache)   

bq = bqclient.BigQueryClient(http, decorator)
```

Is there any more code I should put to clarify the situation? Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Shan

Comment: Can you confirm that the client ID/project you are using to make a request to the API is the one where you've set your redirect URIs?

Answer (score 2):

In standard web server OAuth 2.0 flows (authorization code), there are 3 places the redirect_uri is used.  It must be identical in all three places:

1. In the URL you redirect the user to for them to approve access and
   get an authorization code.
2. In the APIs console
3. In the
   server-to-server HTTPS post when exchanging an authorization code
   for an access token (+ maybe a refresh token)

Comment: I just ran into this where I was using server-side logic to generate the redirect_uri for the server-to-server post. I was appending the port # to support dev mode, so in production was generating http://myapp.appspot.com:80/callback, which didn't match the expected http://myapp.appspot.com/callback.

Comment: Hello Ryan, could you please take a look at my question about BigQuery? Thank you!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424860/google-bigquery-redirect-uris-to-the-unc-path

Answer (score 0):

You haver to create an API credentials with next steps on
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Client Oauth Id
Web Type
JavaScript authorized -> https://yourapp.appspot.com

URIs authorized -> https://yourapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback

This is the credentials you have to use in local app before deploy