# Google BigQuery, redirect uris to the UNC path

Tags: web-applications, google-api, google-bigquery, redirect

I'm creating the web application which uses Google BigQuery, which will get the access and refresh token as well.

My web application will be hosted in the intranet, lets say under `http://mywebapp/`

In order to access it one needs the client ID, so I went to console.developers.google.com and tried to create the "Client ID for web application". I have to enter two things there `JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS` and `REDIRECT URIS` and here is my problem:

Google refuses to accept `http://mywebapp/oauth2callback` as redirect uri, but accepts `http://mywebapp/` as javascript origin.

The error is:

> Invalid redirect URI.

Google accepts "`http://mywebapp.com`" and "`http://localhost`", but that doesn't help me.

Ist this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the difference between `origin` and `redirect` URIs.

The origin is, of course, where the connection comes from. This can be your own local network, localhost or an Intranet, as long as the real originating address will match with the one registered in your configuration, everything will go OK.

On the other hand the redirect is where Google Authorization server will send back the request once it has been authorised. In this case providing an internal address is not possible as Google is not able to redirect to those addresses as they're private.

Comment: I can't see the problem here. Google could just return the status code 3xx and set my wish url as location header. Or google could call javascript, something like window.location.href = "myintranetapp?token=" + generated token. There is no need to know more about the url for redirection.